# How to inspect GWT RPC calls in DynaTrace

Tags: gwt, dynatrace

My company is starting to use DynaTrace to monitor some of our apps. I've been charged with trying to interpret some of the results and come up with suggestions for improvement. But I'm not able to find critical information in DynaTrace. I'm hoping a user here can point me in the right direction.

We use GWT for our front-end applications. I'm trying to identify which RPC calls are running slow and need optimizing. But I'm not able to see the actual Request Message Body, so I don't know which RPC method is being called. They all look the same.

I've managed to find this information (identifying information removed):

```
Node Details
Method: Web request
Class:  Web server
Argument:   [GWT Module Base URL]/esservice
Return: 
Agent:  IIS_CODEDEV_QA[IIS 7.5-ASP.NET%20v4.0]@codedev2:0
API:    Web server
Thread Name:     <0>
Elapsed Time [ms]:  0.00

Time Details    Total   Exec    %
Execution Time [ms]:    15671.72    1.07    0.01
CPU Time [ms]:  -   -   0.00
Sync Time [ms]: -   -   -
Wait Time [ms]: -   -   -
Runtime Suspension Time [ms]:   -   -   -
Source Information
File Name:  Web server  Statement number:   -

Web Requests Details
HTTP Method:    POST
URI:    [GWT Module Base URL]/esservice
Query:  -
HTTP Tag:    
Servlet Name:   -
Web Application Id: -
Client IP:  192.168.132.159
Host:   myapp.myCompany.com
Response Status:    200 - OK
Transferred Bytes   Total   Header  Body
Request:    3.39 KB 3.18 KB 220 Bytes
Response:   492 Bytes   226 Bytes   266 Bytes

Request Headers
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
referer:    https://myapp.myCompany.com/application/dashboard
```

There is alot of detail here, which is good. But it's useless to me without the POST message body. The Argument line is always the same because all the requests are passed though the same RPC servlet. It's the content of the message body that identifies what action is being taken. Without that I have no idea what this request was doing. Some requests take 4000 ms, other take 40. I'd really like to see what the 4000 ms requests are asking for so we can figure out what's causing the bottleneck.

I'm getting this information from the web request in the PurePath Tree.

Is there another place in DynaTrace that I can get this information? I'm not administering the DynaTrace server, so I only have access to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Dynatrace allows you to capture POST Headers. In your System Profile you can configure for your Web Server but also Java Tier to capture thes paramters. For the Web Server you need to open the Properties for the Web Server Sensor. For Java it is the Servlet Sensor. The bottom table in that dialog allows you to specify which parameters you want to capture. if you leave the name field blank ALL paramters will be captured. They will then show up in the details dialog in the PurePath.
How to get to these properties? Edit your System Profile -> Expand the Tier Name -> click on Sensor Configuration -> click on Properties next to the Web Server or Servlet Sensor
Also - if you want somebody to look at your data. I have a program called "Share Your PurePath" - http://bit.ly/sharepurepath. Feel free to export some of your PurePaths and I give you feedback on how to analyze it

Andi

Answer (score 0):

You have to inform dynaTrace about the specific parameter(s) you want to collect.

Go to the tier containing the Web server where the dtwsagent is running, and in the Sensor Configuration click on Properties of the Web Server sensor pack.

Hope it helps!

I created a screenshot of such settings, but unfortunately, although I use this site I just registered and I cannot post images yes (since I don't have 10 reputation).